# Is "have a face like a fiddle" the same as "have a face as long as a fiddle"?

Tags: meaning

I found these idioms and I believe that they transmit the same feeling of sadness. I found "have a face as long as a wet weekend" as well.

Answer (score 1):

Without any context I would say that "face like a fiddle" can be taken more literally, maybe the writer thinks this person's face literally looks like a fiddle. I believe it is complimentary, like pretty face, although I may well be wrong.

The second phrase "as long as a fiddle" definitely means sadness, long face is quite unambiguous in English and the rest is just a simile.